# Sacar el menor de los números ingresados en un for y mostrarlo por pantalla. SIN MIN_VALUE/MAX_VALUE

Tags: java, bucle-for

**Enunciado del problema:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Acá les dejo el codigo que tengo hecho, a la hora de mostrarme el gusto de helado con menos calorias, me muestra solamente el texto pero la variable está en blanco, intenté muchas cosas, y lo que mas logico me parece es poner ese IF al final del switch original, el tema es que tampoco podemos usar MAX_value y MIN_value.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    do {
        System.out.println("Ingrese el tamaño del pote: ");
        pote = input.nextLine();

        do {
            switch (pote) {
```

//----------------------------------------------------------------CASO CHICO------------------------------------------------------------

```
            case "g":
                System.out.println("c");
                System.out.println("de cuantos gustos lo queres? 1,2,3,4");
                cantGustos = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                while (cantGustos < 0 || cantGustos > 4) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: la cant de gustos debe ser entre 1 y 4");
                    cantGustos = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                }
                switch (cantGustos) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("caso 1");
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del gusto: ");
                    nombreGusto = input.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Cant de calorias para " + nombreGusto + "?");
                    cantCalorias = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("caso 2");
                    for (int j = 1; j <= cantGustos; j++) {
                        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del gusto n°" + j);
                        nombreGusto = input.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Cant de calorias para " + nombreGusto + "?");
                        cantCalorias = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("caso 3");
                    for (int j = 1; j <= cantGustos; j++) {
                        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del gusto n°" + j);
                        nombreGusto = input.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Cant de calorias para " + nombreGusto + "?");
                        cantCalorias = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("caso 4");
                    for (int j = 1; j <= cantGustos; j++) {
                        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del gusto n°" + j);
                        nombreGusto = input.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Cant de calorias para " + nombreGusto + "?");
                        cantCalorias = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                    }

                    break;
                }
                cantCalorias = cantMayorCalorias;
                if (cantCalorias < cantMenorCalorias) {
                    cantMenorCalorias = cantCalorias;
                    nombreGustoMenosCal = nombreGusto;      
                }
                System.out.println("El gusto " + nombreGustoMenosCal + " es el que menos calorias tiene!");
            }
            contChico++;
            break;
```

Answer (score 2):

dado que en tu case 2,3,4 solo aplica la comparación para obtener el gusto con menor calorías,puedes simplificarlo de la siguiente manera

```
case 2,3,4:
```

para obtener el menor gusto de calorías primero debes obtener el mayor y esta evaluación debes realizarla dentro del bucle for para que los datos no se pierdan como esta pasando en tu código

```
//obtiene el mayor
if (cantCalorias>cantMayorCalorias ) { 
    cantMayorCalorias = cantCalorias; 
//obtienes el menor con su nombre correspondiente  
 }else if(cantCalorias<cantMayorCalorias){
   cantMenorCalorias=cantCalorias;
 nombreGustoMenosCal = nombreGusto;
}
```

Aplicado lo mencionado tu código quedaría así

```
System.out.println("c");
                System.out.println("de cuantos gustos lo queres? 1,2,3,4");

                int cantGustos = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                while (cantGustos < 0 || cantGustos > 4) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR: la cant de gustos debe ser entre 1 y 4");
                    cantGustos = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                }

                switch (cantGustos) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("caso 1");
                    System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del gusto: ");
                    nombreGusto = input.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Cant de calorias para " + nombreGusto + "?");
                    cantCalorias = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                    break;
              
                case 2,3,4:
                    for (int j = 1; j <= cantGustos; j++) {
                        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del gusto n°" + j);
                        nombreGusto = input.nextLine();
                        System.out.println("Cant de calorias para " + nombreGusto + "?");
                        cantCalorias = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                    
                        if (cantCalorias>cantMayorCalorias ) { 
                            cantMayorCalorias = cantCalorias;   
                                
                        }else if(cantCalorias<cantMayorCalorias){
                           cantMenorCalorias=cantCalorias;
                           nombreGustoMenosCal = nombreGusto;

                        }

                }
            
                System.out.println("El gusto " + nombreGustoMenosCal + " es el que menos calorias tiene! "+ cantMenorCalorias);
               break;
             }
```